# Updating Parse User information locally without having to log out and log in again in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have an app that uses Parse as a backend server.  The user information is stored and can be changed via an Edit Profile activity.  The problem I am having is this:
1.  The information gets changed on the Parse server correctly.
2.  The information doesn't get updated on the app unless I log out, then log back in which forces the user information to be retrieved from Parse.
3.  I don't want to force the user to log out/log in each time they change information.  Is there a way to refresh the current Parse User information another way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this through a few options. First, you can add a [SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) which can surround the main layout and users can swipe down to refresh content. This would mean you override [OnRefreshListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener.html)'s onRefresh method to call fetch() on the objects from Parse you wanted to refresh, and update the UI (notifyDatasetChanged incase of a ListView/RecyclerView/etc).

Another option, you can provide a refresh button somewhere in the User Interface, most likely the Actionbar. This would be the same process as the SwipeRefreshLayout, but you right make it a click listener instead that calls a similar method you defined in the onRefresh method from the SwipeRefreshLayout.

Rememeber to preform the ParseObject fetch calls in an AsyncThread, and upon the successful fetch update the UI. You are changing information on Parse via your Edit Profile activity, and it updates on the server and fixes when you logout / log back in because you are just fetching everything again when you are logged back in.

Since you are updating information in one Activity, and returning to another, you could pass information via an Intent as well for returning the updates to your user interface, (while at the same time the backend is updated with this information). You could make it so the EditProfileActivity is called via an Intent by [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) from your MainActivity, and then pass information back via a Bundle and Intent. Ex below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("name", nameEdit.getText().toString());
extras.putString("email", emailEdit.getText().toString());
intent.putExtras(extras);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent); //Assuming edit went okay
finish();
```

Then in your MainActivity:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
         Intent data) {
      if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
           Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
           //Deal with getting extras here
      }
 }
```

The above solution would assume you know what extras are being passed every time, and may not be preferred since user's may or may not actually edit all fields, or all fields might be too much information to pass. In which case, the fetch() would be a good option.

Comment: I was getting the information from Parse and from the Intent extras correctly.  The problem I was having was with the local user on the app. I was able to track down the problem.  It wasn't with the query, but more so the current Parse user.  If I made changes to the user's data, it wasn't reflected locally until I called getCurrentUser().fetch()

I guess this forced a refresh of the local user on the app.  Seems to be working correctly now!

Answer (score 0):

you just need to update information that the user change to his/her profile . or if you have using a local DB model of parse user in your app you can update the user by ParseUser.getCurrentUser();